# cypress fails tests randomly in headless mode but all passes all tests in real browse

Tags: typescript, cypress

I use Cypress 9.5 to test application in Angular 13. As a backend I have local server in PHP.

I have bunch of tests. When I run them in browser they all pass several times. When I run in headless mode they fail quite randomly. In both cases I use built-in electron browser.

In my tests I have log in as command using `cy.request` and storing required user data in `sessionStorage`. Then when I want to visit main page - login dialog appears.

How can I debug this to find a root cause?

Hint: watching videos from tests I can observe big lags in refreshing rendered image comparing to real browser.

Comment: Hi. Please attach some failure descriptions of your run for a better understanding. It might be related to your test structure and how you defined your actions. So, without any other details 'yet' I do suspect some race conditions, as usually cypress runs faster on headless mode, especially since you're using a local server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a similar issue, and after disabled the video, the ghost is gone.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `video:true`

from the cypress.config.js (v10) or cypress.json in version less than 10.

Try hitting the test in headless mode, the test will run without any errors.